# Is it possible to create temp or infile variable instead of creating a new feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, buffer, time

I am creating a small script which requires to run a Buffer_analyst tool. The help of this function says that I have to set a path where the function will save the output. Is it possible to store the output in a file/script/fuction variable or a temp file instead of saving it permanently to my drive?

The help says that I have to do this:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(input_file, output_file, buffer)
```

but I would like to get something like this:

```
output_file = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(input_file, buffer)
```

or this:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(input_file, temp_file, buffer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IN_MEMORY workspace. This is system RAM which behaves like a simplified geodatabase. This as it says is in memory and therefore if ArcMap blows up or your code crashes you lose it. You can export out from IN_MEMORY if required.

So in your example you might set `temp_file` to be this:

```
temp_file = r"IN_MEMORY\myTempFile"
```

Note no spaces and it does not start with a number. There is lots of information in the Help file, simply search for IN_MEMORY.